# Array of Dictionaries, Empty Dictionary, Keep Array Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have a `NSMutableArray` (tripHistory) that gets a `NSMutableDictionary` (currentUpdate) added to it every second with new data.

```
[currentUpdate setObject:testVariable forKey:@"Test"];
[tripHistory addObject:currentUpdate];
[currentUpdate removeAllObjects];
```

Yet when I loop through `tripHistory` calling `[[tripHistory objectAtIndex:i] description]` everything is null.

My loop is as follows:

```
for (int i=0; i<[tripHistory count]; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [[tripHistory objectAtIndex:i] description]);
}
```

To initialize my variables, the following code is called only for the first update.

```
tripHistory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
currentUpdate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an object to an NSArray doesn't make a copy of it. All that happens is its reference count is incremented. Therefore `currentUpdate` and the NSDictionary added to `tripHistory` are one-and-the-same. If you remove objects from `currentUpdate` you are also removing objects from the NSDictionary in `tripHistory`.

After adding currentUpdate to tripHistory all you need to do is release currentUpdate and start again with a new empty NSDictionary for the next update.

Comment: How can I force-release it with ARC enabled?

Comment: Got it! I just     currentUpdate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; every time it updates.

Comment: You don't. Just re-assign a new dictionary to it when you start the next update:  `currentUpdate = [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Comment: Yes, exactly! You beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

Do not remove objects. Dictionary and array are keeping references to the same objects. If you want to add another dict to array then release first dict and create a new one

Answer (score 2):

You are removing all of the contents of the dictionary. Adding the dictionary to your array doesn't make a copy: The array will retain a reference to the dictionary, which you proceed to empty out each time you add something to it.

You should allocate a new dictionary each time through the loop and then add that dictionary o the array. If you are not using garbage collection or ARC you should also release the dictionary after it is added to the array.

Comment: This worked and you also addressed my ARC concern. Awesome. Thank you!